# Django if statement not working inside of a for loop in templates

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

So I want to display all the posts from the user, in their profile while logged in, but can't seem to figure out how to do it. This is my template:

```
{% for post in posts %}

    {% if user.username == post.author %}

        <div class="container col-lg-8 ml-lg-5">
            <div class="box">
                
                <a href="#"><img class="rounded-circle account-image"  src="{{ 
                post.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="" ></a>
                <a href="#"><h4 style="float: left;">{{post.author}}</h4></a>
                
                    <small>{{post.date_posted}}</small>
                
                
                <hr width="82%" align="right">
                <br>
                <div class=""> <p>{{post.content}}</p></div>
        
                
                
            
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is my model:
class Post(models.Model):

```
content = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It doesn't show me any errors, it just doesn't work. When I try removing the if statement, it works, but shows me every post by every user

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing the current user's username to the post's user instance. Try this instead:

```
    {% if user == post.author %}
```

Edit:
If you're not doing anything with the posts that the user didn't make, you should really do that filtering in the view so the template is simpler.